# Problem in removing a table with large object in postgresql

Tags: python, database, postgresql, odoo, odoo-11

My database has one table named `pg_largeobjects`.

I want to truncate the whole table and tried many things so far, like:

> - VACUUM FULL ANALYZE pg_largeobject
> - lo_unlink
> - backup database by excluding that particular table.
> - restore database by excluding that particular table (Failed).

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To remove all large objects, run

```
SELECT lo_unlink(oid) FROM pg_largeobject_metadata;
```

Then you can `VACUUM` both `pg_largeobject` and `pg_largeobject_metadata` to reclaim the space (because the tables are empty).